# JavaFX Adding Dynamic Tabs Permanently

Tags: javafx, dynamic, tabs, permanent

Is there a way where I could add a permanent tab in javafx dynamically? I mean, I have already created a code which can add a tab dynamically on a button click, but when I close the window and open it again, the tab I just added is gone.

Here's my code snippet..

```
  //on button click
  @FXML
  private void addNewTab(ActionEvent event) {
    add_tab_button.setOnAction(e -> {
        main_tab.getTabs().add(createTab()); //main_tab is the TabPane
        main_tab.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
    });
  }

  //the new tab to be created
  private Tab createTab() {
    tabIndex++;
    Tab newTab = new Tab ("Tab " + tabIndex);
    //content of tab goes here..

    return newTab;
  }
```

Everything goes well, except that, again, when I close the window and open it again, the newly created tab gets removed.. Is there a way to add it permanently? As if I'm overriding the fxml file of the view?

Comment: You need to persist into something (a file or database), then try to read from that when you open the window.

Comment: What do you mean on closing the window? Closing the whole app or just a separate window which was opened earlier but the app still runs? In the first case you can use the suggested solution by @Jai, on the second case you can persist them in some implementation of the `Collection`

Comment: How you can recover your tab , i mean how you can open it again ? as i see, your button  method builds a new tab not recover the closable tabs.And if you want save your tabs ,you should save your tab to specified XML file ,it is a suggested solution.

Comment: @Sunflame By closing the window, I mean the separate window, but the whole application is still running. But since you brought it up, same thing happens when I stop the entire application - the tab I just created will be gone, the next time I run the application again.